# Update Recyclerview inside a childfragment of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a fragment which consists of a viewpager. The viewpager has three fragments. I want to update to the list inside the childfragment of viewpager from the parent fragment. How to do that? I have no idea, any help would be really appreciated.

Regarding any queries feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

MainFragment

```
MyContactUserFragment frag = (MyContactUserFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter_users.getItem(mViewPager_users.getCurrentItem());
                if (frag != null) {
                    frag.sendContactsQuery(newText);
                }
```

ChildFragment

```
public void sendContactsQuery(String query) {
        updateListAllEvents(query);
    }

 public void updateListAllEvents(String query) {

            mAdapter = new MyContactUserAdapter((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), sortedData);

            /*rView.setAdapter(mAdapter);*/
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter is null");
            }
            if (rView == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Rview is null");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see the recyclerview is null when i call the method of child fragment.

Comment: Don't you have reference to child fragments in parent fragment?

Comment: Yes I have, but when I call the method of child fragment through that reference, the views are null. So I am getting null pointer exception. Can you please provide any example.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some of your code where you're having trouble. So that way we can help you better.

Comment: edited my question ,please check

Comment: You have to make  sure that you call the method `sendContactsQuery()` after or inside fragment's 'onCreateView()' method. As per my knowledge, you are getting `null pointer exception` because the fragment's layout isn't created yet. So you have to wait until it gets created.

Comment: And one more thing, please make sure that RecyclerView in your XML is wrapped inside another layout i.e. FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.